# C++ macro for unique class name

Tags: c++

I'm to define a macro which generates classname from another classname (as macro argument) . Something like

```
#define GenerateClass(InputType) \
class GeneratedClass_##InputType { \
};
```

However, when InputType contains namespace, the generated classname is not valid. I can think of following possible ways:
1. Use random number (or globally unique number) as component of the generated class. The type name is just for registering so the real name does not matter from end user perspective.
2. Convert InputType to canonical name.
3. Other way of generating canonical name.

Is there way to do either of the way?

Comment: If the type name does not matter for other code, why do you need to generate it?

Comment: The generated class is sent to another macro for registering, within the macro I'm to write. I just did not put that part in the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply enclose your use of the macro:

```
namespace foo {
    GenerateClass(bar);
}
```

Of course that puts the generated class into the same namespace.  If you don't want that, make a new macro which takes the namespace as a separate parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If the name doesn't matter, then could it be a template specialization instead of an identifier?

```
template <class> class GeneratedClass;

#define GenerateClass(InputType)                \
template <> class GeneratedClass<InputType> {   \
   // ... other code?                           \
};
```

Depending on what else you do with `InputType`, you might be able to just use a class template directly and not need to specialize it or use a macro at all.

Comment: The class is to be passed to another macro (not written by me) for registering. That macro does not accept macro though.

Comment: @XiaoWu So there's a library macro that requires identifiers as arguments? Do the identifiers need to be unique in the entire program and/or in each translation unit? Perhaps you could edit your question to add more information.